# Local Python Package Not Found

Tags: python, package

I have created a package named `aTask` on my local machine and successfully installed it (as there wasn't an error happened) using `pip install -e ./tasks`. To double check, `pip list | grep aTask` and I got `aTask (0.2.0, /Users/WorkPlace/projects/tasks)`.

But when I have been trying to import to my interpreter, I have an error

```
In [1]: import aTask

ImportError  Traceback (most recent call last) 
<ipython-input-1-d76cc8326300> in <module>() 
----> 1 import aTask

ImportError: No module named aTask
```

Would you please give me a hint to resolve my case? Below I put more details

`setup.py` consists of

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

package_name = 'aTask'
version = '0.2.0'
install_requires = ['pandas==0.21.1', 'numpy==1.13.3', 'scikit-learn==0.19.1', 'scipy==1.0.0']
CLASSIFIERS = [
    'Operating System :: OS Independent',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7'
]
description = 'an example to install a package'

setup(name=package_name,
      description=description,
      author='XXXX',
      version=version,
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['test', 'test.*']),
      platforms=['Any'],
      install_requires=install_requires,
      classifiers=CLASSIFIERS)
```

my folder structure as

```
> tree .
.
├── DataPopulation
│   └── main.py
├── README.md
├── Strategies
│   ├── Exceptions
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── IStrategy.py
│   ├── IStrategy.pyc
│   ├── Algorithms
│   │   ├── SVM.py
│   │   ├── SVM.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── miscellaneous.py
│   │   └── miscellaneous.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── StrategyBasicContext.py
├── StrategyBasicContext.pyc
├── Ultils
│   ├── DataIO
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __init__.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── __init__.pyc
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

Comment: Did you try this in a virtual environment?

Comment: yes, I did. In fact, I'm using Anaconda but I tested without it

Comment: Have you checked if the interpreter is using the same Python installation that pip has installed the package to?

Comment: Try installing with `python -m pip install -e ./tasks`.

Comment: @AmosEgel I have run `!pip list` inside IPython which is supposed to use the same env. I also found `aTask (0.2.0, /Users/WorkPlace/projects/tasks)`